# Eclipse - Java - Parsing Data for android-23 failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, java-8

I have an Android project based on Cordova (Phonegap), which, for security reasons, had to be updated to Cordova 6.0.0 and Android platform 5.1.1.

After performing the Android platform update, I noticed that the API for both - the Android project and CordovaLib had been changed to API 23 (Android 6.0) automatically. I installed all the other files of Android 6.0 via SDK Manager.

I can't seem to build the project any more because the CordovaLib project doesn't have the .jar file hence, the it never gets build to begin with.

Here are some additional information about my environment -

1. JAVA-HOME = jdk1.7.0_79
2. Eclipse->Widows->Preferences->Java->Compiler = 1.7
3. Eclipse->Widows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs = jdk1.7.0_79
4. Running Eclipse Kepler Java EE IDE for Web Developers

I restarted Eclipse and got this error -

> Parsing Data for android-23 failed
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, anything > API 21 is not supported by Eclipse ADT anymore. Google moved to their own IDE, Android Studio. Installed SDK for API 23 and used Android Studio and everything worked fine.